# Visual Studio 6 : How to change the workspace file name?

Tags: visual-studio, file, visual-c++-6, rename, workspace

When using VC++6 sp6, how can I change the workspace file name?

The workspace directory contains three main files with the following file extensions. When I tried changing the filenames while preserving the respective file extension, I get a whole bunch of errors and warnings when I tried to recompile the projects contained in that workspace. Before the change of filename, there are no errors however.

- .dsw
- .ncb
- .opt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you also rename the name within the .dsw so it will point to the right file(s)?